# Return intersection of subdocument array with user defined array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use Mongo Aggregation Framework to find out intersection between an array inside my document AND another user defined array. 
I don't get a correct result and my guess is its because of the fact that I have array inside of an array.

Here is my data set.

My documents:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "pendingEntries" : [ 
        {
            "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65f"),
            "tags" : [ 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "owner",
                    "tagValue" : "john"
                }, 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "ErrorCode",
                    "tagValue" : "7001"
                }, 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "ErrorDescription",
                    "tagValue" : "error123"
                }
            ],
            "entryTime" : ISODate("2016-04-04T00:26:43.167Z")
        }
    ]
},

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "pendingEntries" : [ 
        {
            "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65d"),
            "tags" : [ 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "owner",
                    "tagValue" : "peter"
                }, 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "ErrorCode",
                    "tagValue" : "6001"
                }, 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "JIRA",
                    "tagValue" : "Oabc-123"
                }
            ],
            "entryTime" : ISODate("2016-04-04T00:26:43.167Z")
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "pendingEntries" : [ 
        {
            "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65c"),
            "tags" : [ 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "owner",
                    "tagValue" : "abc"
                }, 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "ErrorCode",
                    "tagValue" : "6001"
                }, 
                {
                    "tagKey" : "JIRA",
                    "tagValue" : "abc-123"
                }
            ],
            "entryTime" : ISODate("2016-04-04T00:26:43.167Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

My Query:

```
db.entrylike.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { "pendingEntries.entryID": 1, "common": { $setIntersection: [ "$pendingEntries.tags", [{ "tagKey" : "ErrorCode", "tagValue" : "7001" }] ] } } }
   ]
)
```

Result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "pendingEntries" : [ 
                {
                    "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65f")
                }
            ],
            "common" : []
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "pendingEntries" : [ 
                {
                    "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65d")
                }
            ],
            "common" : []
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "pendingEntries" : [ 
                {
                    "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65c")
                }
            ],
            "common" : []
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I am not expecting first common field to be empty. Can someone let me know what is it that I am doing wrong? Or any work arounds that I can take.

I am using mongodb 3.0.8. I am aware of the fact that Mongodb 3.2 can offer some features which will fulfill my needs but 3.2 upgrade is not in our pipeline soon and I am looking to resolve this using Mongo3.0 if possible.

My goal is to either replace tags array with the common elements from the user defined list or add a new field with common elements. My am trying to to the later in my example.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you the common field is empty is because your "pendingEntries" array and your user defined array have not element in common. What you really want is to return an array that contains the elements that appear in your "tags" array and your user defined array. To do that you can simply use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator and apply the [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator to each subdocument "tags" in the "pendingEntries" array.

```js
db.entrylike.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "common": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$pendingEntries", 
                "as": "p",
                "in": { 
                    "entryID": "$$p.entryID",
                    "tags": { 
                        "$setIntersection": [ 
                            "$$p.tags", 
                            { "$literal": [
                                { 
                                    "tagKey" : "ErrorCode", 
                                    "tagValue" : "7001" 
                                }
                            ]}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "common" : [
        {
            "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65f"),
            "tags" : [
                {
                    "tagKey" : "ErrorCode",
                    "tagValue" : "7001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "common" : [
        {
            "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65d"),
            "tags" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "common" : [
        {
            "entryID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e65c"),
            "tags" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `$literal` should not be needed in this context since it is perfectly fine to simply notate the single element array directly inside `$setIntersection`. Also worth noting that `$setIntersection` only works here when the elements are in the "exact" order, and a `[{ "tagValue": "7001", "tagKey": "ErrorCode" }]` notation would therefore "not" be a match, where either the comparison or stored data was not in that order of keys. The main point if of course to use `$map` to access the elements and return the altered form. Which is as stated.

Comment: @NeilLunn I also though that `$literal` was not needed but without `$literal`, the query failed with *"FieldPath 'ErrorCode' doesn't start with $"*

Comment: You must have had a typo. `db.collection.aggregate({ "$project": { "a": { "$setIntersection": [["a","b"],["b"]] } }})` is a simple reproducible case.

Comment: @NeilLunn weird,  it doesn't work if it's an array of sub-documents. `db.collection.aggregate({ "$project": { "a": { "$setIntersection": [["a","b"],[{'a': "b"}]] } }})` will fail.
I am on v3.2 didn't check other version.

Comment: Well yes it is because of the "other version" here since v3.2.x allows expressions directly within array declarations. But you [asked that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36639188/2313887) separately ( and probably a good thing since it is a different question ) on this site now.