# $setIntersection failed with array of subdocuments that are not in the collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider the following document:

```js
{
    "item1" : [
        {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 2
        }
    ],
    "item2" : [ "a", "b" ]
}
```

The following query:

```js
db.test.aggregate([ 
    { "$project": { "items": { "$setIntersection": [ "$item1", "$item2" ] } }}
])
```

returns the expected result:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5710785387756a4a75cbe0d1"), "a" : [ ] }
```

If the document looks like this:

```js
{ "item2" : [ "a", "b" ] }
```

Then:

```js
db.test.aggregate([ { "$project": { 
    "a": { "$setIntersection": [ "$item2", [ "a" ] ] } } } 
])
```

Yields:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5710785387756a4a75cbe0d1"), "a" : [ "a" ] }
```

But

```js
db.test.aggregate([         
    { "$project": { "items": { "$setIntersection": [ "$item2", [ { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } ] ] } } } 
])
```

failed with :

> "errmsg" : "field inclusion is not allowed inside of $expressions"

And:

```js
db.test.aggregate([ { "$project": { 
    "items": { "$setIntersection": [ "$item2", [ { "a": "b" } ] ] } } } 
])
```

failed with:

> "errmsg" : "FieldPath 'b' doesn't start with $"

The only way to make this work is to use the `$literal` operator.

Why should we use the [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator if [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) arguments are array of sub-documents and not a **field** in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a compatibility changes in MongoDB 3.2 thus is the expected behavior as mentioned in the [Aggregation Compatibility Changes in MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-compatibility/#aggregation-compatibility-changes):

> Array elements are no longer treated as literals in the aggregation pipeline. Instead, each element of an array is now parsed as an expression. To treat the element as a literal instead of an expression, use the [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal) operator to create a literal value.

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be an artifact of MongoDB 3.2 which incorporated a change that allows arrays to be notated while directly interpolating properties of the document.

For example, with a document like:

```js
 { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4 }
```

Then you are "now" allowed to notate those elements inside an array, like:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "array": [
           { "field1": "$a", "field2": "$b" },
           { "field1": "$c", "field2": "$d" }
        ]
    }}
])
```

In previous versions ( in this case MongoDB 2.6 ) you would instead need to use this [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) expression:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "array": {
            "$map": {
                "input": ["A","B"],
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": {
                        "if": { "$eq": [ "$$el", "A" ] },
                        "then": { "field1": "$a", "field2": "$b" },
                        "else": { "field1": "$c", "field2": "$c" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Or in prior versions to that then something a bit more long winded using `$unwind` and `$group`, but the same basic principle of transposing a "source" array with other data. The main point though is the change in notation allowed in MongoDB 3.2, which would otherwise "error" in a prior version.

Therefore in a prior version, say MongoDB 2.6.x where [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) is supported then the following works just fine, since all values are considered "literal" unless actually referencing an array present in the document:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "a": { 
      "$setIntersection": [
        [{"a": 1}],
        [{"a": 1}]
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Provided of course that `"collection"` as a collection actually has something in it.

But since MongoDB 3.2 allows a different syntax for "interpolated arrays", it now expects the "right side" to evaluate to a property from the document or other valid expression. So now the [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) syntax is required:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "a": { 
      "$setIntersection": [
        { "$literal": [{"a": 1}] },
        { "$literal": [{"a": 1}] }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

This generally comes down to the saying that *"you can't have your cake and eat it too"*. The "new" syntax allows you to express array content with "interpolations" in a nice way without resorting to other expressions to "coerce" the content into an array form.

The consequence of this is that **every** such expression is now expecting "values" to resolve to a property or expression rather than being directly considered a "literal", and where you mean that to be so, you are now required to express that using the [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator.

So it is in fact a "breaking" change in allowed syntax between versions. But one that most people should easily live with.